# Problems with detail UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, view, interface

I'm trying to build my iOS app's interface. Starting over and over with new project i'm still getting a problem with a detail view's controls (see picture).

Here i got the screenshots:

*detail view shows when user touch to the UITableView row. You can see the difference between my design and final result on the simulator screen - this is the problem*

[image]

*main xib design*

[image]

*this is how i open the detail view:*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Design looks OK, code OK. Check out the constraints of the detail view or just switch off the new IB format.

Comment: You might want to put a breakpoint in your app, somewhere after the screen presentation is done, and then in your debugger, type in `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` which will tell you what's going on (e.g. is it the labels that are messed up, or their superview). Also, are you using auto layout? If so, the constraints should be reviewed.

Comment: Autolayout - that is the source of bugs in my design. I just switched it off on the detail xib and now all controls are in its right places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[autolayout](/questions/tagged/autolayout) - that is the source of bugs in my design. I just switched it off on the detail xib and now all controls are in its right places

thank you Rob